# cloud function error, node module node-xlsx, Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: node.js, weixinjsbridge, node-xlsx, tencent-cloud

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
> at xlsx (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\node-xlsx\lib\xlsx\xlsx.js:174:23)
> at Object.build (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\node-xlsx\lib\node-xlsx.js:14:16)
> at d.exports.main [as handler] (cloudfunctions\excel\index.js:57:29)
> at \code\package.nw\js\common\cloud-functions-debugger-server\worker\node.js:1:44797
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Oringial it works fine.
However,this error came after I npm install moment and npm audit fix several vunerabilities.

I locate the error came from package's script. but how to change? I have removed node modules and reinstalled, it didn't work.

xlsx\xlsx.js:174:23

> w = file.worksheets.length;

```
//index.js of cloud function to call node-xlsx
const cloud = require('wx-server-sdk')
const moment = require("moment-timezone")
cloud.init({ 
  traceUser: true,
  env: cloud.DYNAMIC_CURRENT_ENV })

const xlsx = require('node-xlsx');

exports.main = async(event, context) => {
  try {
    let {userdata} = event
    
      // javascript date
    //  console.log(new Date()); // 2021-03-16T08:04:07.441Z (UTC+0
    //  console.log(moment().tz("Asia/Shanghai").format()); // 2021-03-16T16:04:07+08:00 (UTC+8)
    let curDate = moment().tz("Asia/Shanghai").format();
    //let curDate =new Date().toISOString()
    //1,
    let dataCVS = 'order_list_'+curDate+'.xlsx'
    //2，
    let alldata = [];
    //let row = ['status','receiver']; //
    let row=['_id' , 'orderDate', 'region','address','receiver','phone'
    ,'cloth_id','cloth_notes','num','cloth_price','totalPrice','status']
    alldata.push(row);
    console.log('excel before loop:'+alldata)
    for (let key in userdata) {
      
      for (let i in userdata[key]['product']){
        let arr = [];
        arr.push(userdata[key]._id);
        arr.push(userdata[key].orderDate);
        arr.push(userdata[key]['address'].region[0]+'-'
        +userdata[key]['address'].region[1]+'-'
        +userdata[key]['address'].region[2]);
        arr.push(userdata[key]['address'].address);
        arr.push(userdata[key]['address'].receiver);
        arr.push(userdata[key]['address'].phone);

        arr.push(userdata[key]['product'][i].cloth_id);
        arr.push(userdata[key]['product'][i].cloth_notes);
        arr.push(userdata[key]['product'][i].cloth_price);
        arr.push(userdata[key]['product'][i].num);
        arr.push(userdata[key].totalPrice);
        arr.push(userdata[key].status);
        alldata.push(arr)
      }
    }
    //console.log('excel has data:'+alldata)
    //3，
    **var buffer = await xlsx.build([{
      name: "mySheetName",
      data: alldata
    }]);**
    console.log('buffer have data : '+buffer);
    //4，
    return await cloud.uploadFile({
      cloudPath: dataCVS,
      fileContent: buffer, //
      
    })

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    return e
  }
}
```

after changing to xlsx, it has another error below. I found I need to change
fileContent: buffer to fileContent: excelbuffer
at Function.DelayedStream.create (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
at FormData.CombinedStream.append (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:45:37)
at FormData.append (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:74:3)
at appendFormValue (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\request\request.js:326:21)
at Request.init (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\request\request.js:337:11)
at new Request (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\request\request.js:127:8)
at Object.request [as default] (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules\request\index.js:53:10)
at body (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules@cloudbase\node-sdk\lib\storage\index.js:41:26)
at new Promise ()
at Object.uploadFile (cloudfunctions\excel\node_modules@cloudbase\node-sdk\lib\storage\index.js:40:22)